# About the fractional part

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I want to prove this result:

If $a+b$ is an integer and $0<b<1$ implies that the **fractional part** of $a$ is just $1-b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know $a + b \equiv 0 \pmod1$. Write $a = n + f$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0\leq f<1$.

Then $n + f + b \equiv f + b \equiv 0 \pmod1$. Since both $f, b < 1$, it must be that $f+b = 1$.